# Proving Convexity of MSE

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I was going through notes on convexity and it is mentioned as following

for any $\lambda ∈ [0,1]$ and
$w, w′$

$$L(\lambda w + (1 − \lambda)w′) − (\lambda L(w) + (1 − \lambda)L(w′)) ≤ 0$$

where $$L(w) = \frac{1}{2N}|| y - Xw||^2_2$$

The solution given is LHS = $$-\frac{1}{2N}\lambda(1-\lambda)||X(w-w')||^2_2$$

Whereas when I try to solve it myself by expanding the squares I keep getting
$$-\frac{1}{N}\lambda(1-\lambda)X^2ww'$$

**Edit:** I know what I did wrong and why my solution is wrong but I still cant get the correct answer.

Can anyone please explain what am i missing? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a real Hilbert space with inner product $\langle \cdot \, | \, \cdot \rangle,$ and let $x$ and $y$ be in $\mathcal{H}.$ Then, for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R},$
$$ \| \alpha x + (1 - \alpha) y \|^2 + \alpha (1 - \alpha) \| x - y \|^2 = \alpha \| x \|^2 + (1 - \alpha) \| y \|^2. $$
Additionally, since
$$ (\forall \alpha \in \,]0,1[) ~~ \alpha (1 - \alpha) \| x - y \|^2 \geq 0,$$
we have,
\begin{align*}
(\forall \alpha \in \,]0,1[) ~~ \| \alpha x + (1 - \alpha) y \|^2 &= \alpha \| x \|^2 + (1 - \alpha) \| y \|^2 - \alpha (1 - \alpha) \| x - y \|^2 \\
&\leq \alpha \| x \|^2 + (1 - \alpha) \| y \|^2,
\end{align*}
so the function $\|\cdot \|^2$ is convex.

Indeed, we have

- $\| \alpha x + (1 - \alpha) y \|^2 = \alpha^2 \| x \|^2 + \| y \|^2 + \alpha^2 \| y \|^2 - 2 \alpha \| y \|^2 + 2 \alpha (1 - \alpha) \langle x \, | \, y \rangle;$
- $\alpha (1 - \alpha) \| x - y \|^2 = \alpha \| x \|^2 - \alpha^2 \| x \|^2 + \alpha \| y \|^2 - \alpha^2 \| y \|^2 - 2 \alpha (1 - \alpha) \langle x \, | \, y \rangle. $

Summing the above two quantities together yields the desired result. Now, let $\mathcal{K}$ be a real Hilbert space, fix $y \in \mathcal{H},$ let $X : \mathcal{K} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ be linear and continuous, and define

$$ T : \mathcal{K} \rightarrow \mathcal{H} : w \mapsto y - X w. $$
Then $L = \frac{1}{2N} f \circ T,$ where $f = \| \cdot \|^2.$ Since $T$ is affine and $f$ is convex, one can conclude that $L$ is convex as it is the composition of a convex function and an affine function (show that this is true).

Recall that a function $G: \mathcal{K} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ is [affine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/295280/affine-function-definition) if

$$ (\forall x \in \mathcal{K})(\forall y \in \mathcal{K})(\forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}) ~~ G (\lambda x + (1 - \lambda)y) = \lambda G(x) + (1 - \lambda) G(y). $$